Carrying salt tablets, caps , chews, etc
I am training for marathons. I want to carry salt tablets on my long runs and race days but last time I did, the resealable little SaltStick pack of tabs I have got totally closed on me, probably too tight. Has anyone experimented with how to carry the various forms of salt e.g. tabs, chews, caps, etc? Do you carry the resealable pack with you? Or carry the tabs, etc in your race belt? Or is an electrolyte drink the best thing in these situations? All advice is welcome.
Thanks.

It really depends on what you're willing to carry. When I did my marathon training, I put my salt tablets and gels in a zippered armband where I kept my phone and keys. You can probably use this same tactic for a race belt as well.
Another thing I recommend is to make sure that you are able to open the salt packet before you start your run. That usually means cutting the packet by an additional centimeter or two so that it's easier to tear off during the run, but not so much that it causes the salt to leak out during the run before you need it.

I have carried electrolyte capsules for many years in 'snack' size ziploc bags. I buy bottles of the capsules, which is less expensive per serving.  I put all of the capsules I need for my run in one bag and carry it in a front pocket of my running shorts.   With only minimal practice, I was able to take a capsule out, reseal the bag and carry on without any disruption.  I often use a handheld water bottle, which makes this a little more difficult, but it hasn't been a problem.  I  have done hundreds of long runs, plus several marathons and half-marathons this way.
This is definitely something to experiment with during training, so you know that it will work for you on race day.  I have talked to other runners who have tried my approach with electrolytes or other nutrition and had things fall out of their pockets while running.  I haven't had that problem with any of the shorts I wear.  Front pockets are easiest to access, but you may need to try another pocket if the bag doesn't stay put.
